# WiX Installer - how to read sql file content from a folder which reside at same location as .msi

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.6

I want to invoke custom action to execute set of .sql files against given database. I am able to do that using custom action code(in c#) if I hardcode path of folder where my sql files are available.

I want to put this sql scripts folder in same location where my .msi is present. How can I access/find this folder-path from custom action during the time of installation?

I am using Wix 3.6.
I am using dot net bootstrapper to create my setup.exe.

Comment: Did you try SQL Extension? You can pass the Sql Scripts as binary stream. more details: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_sqlscript.htm

Answer (score 2):

The `SqlScript` element in the WiX toolset may do a lot of what you are asking for. It actually stores the scripts as `Binary` streams in the MSI instead of relying on files relative to the MSI. This is an important design decision because there are many cases where your MSI will execute but not have access to the original source media so it would not find the scripts. For example, repair operations can be launched from the cached MSI package. If your custom action was to repair, it would need the original media to get the scripts. This is not very desirable.

If you really want to go down this path, then you'll want to look at using the `SourceDir` directory to get the "source location" of your MSI. As noted above, the source media may not always be available and `SourceDir` will be blank in those cases. To force `SourceDir` to be set, you'll need to add a `ResolveFiles` action. Be careful when scheduling `ResolveFiles` because that will require the original media. If that can't be found, the user will be prompted to insert it again.

The worst case of poor sequencing of `ResolveFiles` is a prompt from source when the user is attempting to uninstall their product. User's are trying to get your application of the machine and they are prevented unless they can find how they originally installed it.  Good way to really upset your users. :)

I highly recommend looking at the `SqlScript` element instead or the source code if you are really interested. It's in the WiX toolset at src\ca\serverca (look for files with "sql" in the name below there).